# Modify category permalink to use post type slug

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, permalinks

I have multiple custom post types and default post type that all need categories. Right now, each post type is using the default category taxonomy.

I would like the archive category taxonomy URL to be `post-type-name/category-name` for custom post types and `/blog/category-name/` for default posts. Then each one of those URLs will just pull in posts of that post type within that category.

The single post views would just be `post-type-name/post-name` while the default post will be `/blog/post-name/`

Is using the default categories the best way of going about this or creating custom taxonomies for each post type?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but it seems like having the same URL format for two types of things might not work, or could be very complicated to deal with. When you go to `/post-type-name/foo`, how would Wordpress know if `foo` is a post-name or a category-name. Perhaps categories at `post-type-name/category-name/` and posts at `post-type-name/category-name/post-name`. This might make your problem easier.

Comment: Yeah, the more I dig into this, I think you're right.